# Lua to JVM compiler?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, lua

Is there a compiler for Lua that compiles to JVM bytecode (and would thus be able to run on Google app engine)?

Answer (score 6):

I know of two lua vms for the jvm

http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaj/

and

http://code.google.com/p/kahlua/

Comment: I believe they both don't compile to JVM bytecodes, which makes them a bit slow. IIRC luaj was around 4-5x slower than regular lua.

Comment: from luaj homepage: "unique direct lua-to-java-bytecode compiling"

Answer (score 0):

Check out [aelua](http://code.google.com/p/aelua/), it's a Lua web framework compatible with AppEngine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Rembulan](https://github.com/mjanicek/rembulan), implementation of Lua 5.3 for JVM.